# Run a program, passing in the current file, from VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, interpreter, vscode-extensions

I am adding a homemade programming language to VS Code, and can't get the interpreter to run my files. The goal is for the extension to run `"myinterpreter.exe ${file}"` or equivalent, when the user hits Debug (or Run, I have no debugging features implemented, so I am going to just ignore any debug information.) I have very little in the way of ideas on how to do this, but I think it should be mostly possible with just `package.json`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think [these docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) cover what you need. What happens when the user hits "Run" or "Debug" is defined in client/.vscode/launch.json. `"runtimeExecutable"` is what you can populate with `"myinterpreter.exe ${file}"`